# how to use this JSON Array..?

Tags: android, json

> **I am trying to use Autosuggesttextview **
>   Json Array

["balakumar",
    "bala",
    "balakumar",
    "bala",
    "bala kumar kumar",
    "balakumar%20kumar",
    "bala%20kumar%20mani",
    "bala%20kuma",
    "balasingh"]

> My Json prase class file

```
    class JsonParse {

    public List<Country> getParseJsonWCF(String sName)
    {
        List<Country> ListData = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String temp=sName.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL js = new URL("http://examplejson/json"+temp);
            URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(line);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
//                JSONObject o=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                Country item=new Country(o.getString("user_name"));
//                ListData.add(item);
//                int value=jsonArray.getInt(i);
//                String.valueOf(value);
//                Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
//                ListData.add(value);
                Country value= (Country) jsonArray.get(i);
                ListData.add(value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ListData;

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to explain what exactly is wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a "out of the box" library to work with json?

I see that you are using Java, the javax.json package would be very useful... If you are using maven you can add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then do:

```
try(JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(/*reader or inputStream*/)) {
    JsonArray array = reader.readArray();
}
```

Although your code show some external classes that could be a library to read json data and then my suggestion is useless. If you are trying to decode the %20 to a space you could use URLDecoder... Example:

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("Jerônimo%20Nunes",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
```

would print `Jerônimo Nunes`